# How did the invasion begin?

Tags: alien-invasion, the-host

I recently watched the movie adaptation of [The Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_%28novel%29) (I have not read the novel).

> In the movie they depict the "Souls" as being very fragile when they are not either in a body or in their spaceship/capsule devices. It also shows that a Soul needs the help of an already compromised human in order to be implanted in another human.

Given this is the case, how did the invasion start? How was the first human taken over by a Soul?

I don't recall this being addressed in the movie version and I was curious if it was talked about in the novel at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - it wasn't talked about in the movie.  However, I believe in the book that;

> They invaded using different hosts, and once the local population was quelled, they no longer needed their other hosts.

Comment: I have also not read the book. Given your answer, is there any information on how the cycle began in the first place?

Comment: Yes there is.  They originally bonded with a physically powerful species for mutual benefit.  Through this species, they were able to colonize other planets.  I think the species was a form of spider.

Comment: That would be good to include in your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The invasion was planned by the Spiders - the first species to be taken over by the souls.

> “Right,” I agreed, surprised at his grasp of the facts at hand. I shouldn't have been surprised—I knew how bright he was, his mind like a thirsty sponge. “We used our Spider selves in the very
>   beginning, to get things started.”
>   “Spiders?”
>   [...]
>   I started to tell Jamie how the offensive had been launched here. The Spiders were our best engineers–the ships they made for us danced nimbly and undetectably through the stars. The Spiders' bodies were almost as useful as their minds: four long legs to each segment–from which they'd earned their nickname on this planet–and twelve-fingered hands on each leg. These six-jointed fingers were as slender and strong as steel threads, capable of the most delicate procedures. About the mass of a cow, but short and lean, the Spiders had no trouble with the first insertions. They were stronger than humans, smarter than humans, and prepared, which the humans were not.…
>   <sub>*The Host*, chapter 21</sub>

So the Spiders prepared the invasion, and then we get an account from Kathy of how it took place:

> “Kathy.” I said her name slowly. Stalling. “Why did you keep your human name? Did it make you feel… more at one? With your host, I mean?” I would have liked to know about Curt's choice as well, but it was such a personal question. It would have been wrong to ask anyone besides Curt for the answer, even his partner. I worried that I'd already been too impolite, but she laughed.
>   “Heavens, no, Wanderer. Haven't I told you this? Hmm. Maybe not, since it's not my job to talk, but to listen. Most of the souls I speak with don't need as much encouragement as you do. Did you know I came to Earth in one of the very first placements, before the humans had any idea we were here? I had human neighbors on both sides. Curt and I had to pretend to be our hosts for several years. Even after we'd settled the immediate area, you never knew when a human might be near. So *Kathy* just became who I was. Besides, the translation of my former name was fourteen words long and did not shorten prettily.” She grinned. The sunlight slanting
>   through the window caught her eyes and sent their silver green reflection dancing on the wall. For a moment, the emerald irises glowed iridescent.
>   [...]
>   “Yes, I chose Curt—and he chose me. At first, of course, it was random chance, an assignment. We bonded, naturally, from spending so much time together, sharing the danger of our mission. As the university's president, Curt had many contacts, you see. Our house was an insertion facility. We would entertain often. Humans would come through our door and our kind would leave. It all had to be very quick and quiet–you know the violence these hosts are prone to. We lived every day with the knowledge that we could meet a final end at any moment. There was constant excitement and frequent fear.
>   “All very good reasons why Curt and I might have formed an attachment and decided to stay together when secrecy was no longer necessary. And I could lie to you, assuage your fears, by telling you that these were the reasons. But…” She shook her head and then seemed to settle deeper into her chair, her eyes boring into me. “In so many millennia, the humans never did figure *love* out. How much is physical, how much in the mind? How much accident and how much fate? Why did perfect matches crumble and impossible couples thrive? I don't know the answers any better than they did. Love simply is where it is. My host loved Curt's host, and that love did not die when the ownership of the minds changed.”
>   <sub>*The Host*, chapter 5</sub>